# How to send a newsletter to all email addresses attached to a content type?

Tags: 7, entities, emails

I have a content type (customers) having an email field (field_email). I need to create a newsletter using those emails that every certain period increase.

I try to use the module Newsletter but I must to re-enter all emails again and new email every time a new customer is registered.
Is there a way to import all emails from my content type, to list the newsletter module?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like [Newsletter](https://www.drupal.org/project/newsletter) supports that.

On the other hand, the [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module has decent [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) support which may make managing your subscribers easier. As far as I know a user account isn't required to subscribe.

Off the top of my head, here is an example of a rule that might automatically add an email address to a subscription list when a new 'Customer' node is created:

```
IF
  (condition) 'After saving new content' (node is created) 
AND
  (condition) 'Entity is of type' (node is 'Customer' type)
AND
  (condition) 'Entity has field' (node has 'email' field) 
THEN
  (action)  'Set a data value' (get value of email field)
THEN
  (action)  'Subscribe an e-mail address to a newsletter'
```

(The full implementation is beyond the scope of this answer but there are plenty of other posts dealing with Rules.)

As for importing email addresses, in both of the 7.x branches there is a "mass subscribe" option at *People > Subscriptions*.